# ConnectionStrings specified in a project App.config not in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings

Tags: entity-framework, app-config

I was trying to get a connection string using the App.config but ran into an issue that perplexed me for some time.  When I ran the code, it would not find the right connection strings. There was a LocalTcpConnection but that was it (and I didn't even define that one, so no idea where that came from).  Where are the connectionStrings that I defined in the App.config?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that only the App.config of the project you launch is actually used (see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15699362/8650122)).  Simply add the string to whatever project you launch with.  This fact was not well defined in the Microsoft Docs I read or in many of the ConnectionString questions here on stack overflow, so I created this Q&A to help any souls as unfortunate as I to run into this problem.